# Should AC coolant pipes be mounted on the exterior?

Tags: hvac

Contractor recently installed a new AC unit and mounted the copper pipes running up the wall on the outside. This is in California, plenty of sunlight and hot days.

- Besides looking unsightly, are there any safety or reliability concerns with this?
- Would sunlight impact the efficiency? Rain will wear out the insulation and tape?
- Is it worth pushing them to redo it and route the pipe from the inside of the wall?

[image]

Comment: How were the pipes originally installed?

Comment: Biggest complaint I’d have is the fact that it is not plumb. I recently repaired significant water damage to a wall that had the line set sweating inside the wall cavity for 15 years.

Comment: There was no ac before, central system is all new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is unsightly, but, depending on the construction of your home, this may have been the best option.

The piping runs up the wall, through the soffit and into the attic. This was a very quick *and inexpensive* way of getting the plumbing into the attic where, presumably, the air handler is.

If the piping had run horizontally directly into the wall then up the interior, it's quite likely that the HVAC company would have had to tear up portions of the interior or exterior of the wall and rip out loads of insulation, possibly hit a bay with ducting, plumbing or electrical runs and may have had to move to a different stud bay, all to get the pipe properly run through the wall and up into the attic. This would have taken *considerably* longer and cost *considerably* more money - demolition, plumbing, insulation, reconstruction, refinishing - but would have looked nicer.

They probably could have quoted you for both options, but, if they're a quality company that's been in business for any period of time, they probably realize you'd have passed out at the cost difference, and once revived, would have chosen the option they went with.

There will be wear and tear on the foam insulation, however, our condenser was installed 25 years ago (yes, it's time for a replacement) and the bit of piping that's outside was wrapped in the same type of foam insulation. We just did some siding last summer and it looked perfectly fine. Our is out of direct sunlight, so if yours gets direct sunlight, maybe it will only last half as long. 10-15 years is the *normal* service life for the condenser unit, so next time around, they'll replace everything anyway.

Should you push them to redo it? Well, you could ask them for a quote, but I'd recommend sitting down when they're ready to deliver it.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way it's done many times. In new construction they may be put underground but if they fail, they are replaced up the exterior wall and through the attic. I must say that it's a pretty sloppy job though. The installers could have made a better effort to keep them straight and up against the wall the entire way. There are shields that are usually placed over the pipes to hide them and further protect the insulation from the elements (see below). The safety and reliability won't be affected by this installation.[image]

Picture from Metal Roofing Screws.

Comment: Covering it up seems like a good idea!